# How to load taxonomy terms from user profile field using entityfieldquery()?

Tags: database, taxonomy-terms

I want to write hook_node_form_alter() and limit taxonomy terms with only user checked terms on his profile in field_companies.
I can't pass the 1st step - load array of user checked terms from field_companies using entityfieldquery.
This code does not work:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$result = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'user')
  ->fieldCondition('field_companies', 'entity_id', $user->uid)
  ->execute();
```

The error message is:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 
Unknown column 'field_data_field_companies0.field_companies_entity_id' in 'where clause': 
SELECT DISTINCT field_data_field_companies0.entity_type 
AS entity_type, field_data_field_companies0.entity_id AS entity_id, field_data_field_companies0.revision_id AS revision_id, field_data_field_companies0.bundle AS bundle
 FROM {field_data_field_companies} field_data_field_companies0 
WHERE (field_data_field_companies0.field_companies_entity_id = :db_condition_placeholder_0) 
AND (field_data_field_companies0.deleted = :db_condition_placeholder_1) 
AND (field_data_field_companies0.entity_type = :db_condition_placeholder_2) ; 
Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 0 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => user ) in function field_sql_storage_field_storage_query() 
(line 632 in file modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module)
```

This query does not give terms, but only array with user[uid]=1 :

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$term_entities = $query
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'user')
  ->entityCondition('entity_id', $user->uid) 
  ->fieldCondition('field_companies', 'tid', 0, '>=')
  ->execute();
```

Comment: It's `target_id` for an entity reference field

Comment: think no, cause my table field_data_field_companies has this structure: http://i57.tinypic.com/28m0lec.png where tid is term id - and i need to get all of them for current user where user is entity_id column.

Comment: EFQ doesn't work that way round. The `fieldCondition` column must be a field column, it can't just be any column in the table. For a taxonomy term that'll be `tid`, you're right.

Comment: ->entityCondition('entity_id', $user->uid) doesn't give solution. may be i need to load terms using ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')?

Comment: That's right, but you still won't get what you're looking for if the term reference field is on the user entity. An EFQ doesn't know about reverse field relationships

Comment: i need to use drupal_query() function to load content using my sql-query ?

Comment: In this case I think you do (it's `db_query()` btw); you could `hook_query_alter()` the EFQ and manipulate it there, but if your storage engine isn't going to change I'd probably hardcode it too

Comment: I've solved the same task in this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/155201/users-have-access-to-add-commerce-products-into-the-store-and-publish-it-how-to   I think there is more efficient way to limit terms. This question was the part of a new task: how to limit terms in node addition form with only user checked on his profile. db_query() is very low-level programming so i need another way

Comment: It's really not "low level programming" @tlito, `db_query()` just allows you to run prepared SQL statements. The example in the answer you've linked to won't help here; in the OP's case, the field is not on the taxonomy term, it's on the user entity.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED with my module user_referenced_taxonomy_terms
code has quality 60%. you need to read it and correct if your fields has other names. this code works in my site.

```
/*displays only user checked companies in node addition form in field_company*/
/* field_companies - user profile field  */
/* field_company - node field */

function profile_taxonomy_on_node_addition_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  global $user;
  //if current user has roles administrator or editor return
  foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
      if (($role == 'administrator') || ($role == 'editor')) return;
  }
  if (isset($form['field_company'])) {
    //get user checked terms companies
    $terms = db_select('field_data_field_companies', 'c')
       ->fields('c', array('field_companies_tid'))
       ->condition('c.entity_id', $user->uid)
       ->execute()
       ->fetchCol();
    if ($terms) {
        //forming array of firms using $terms array
        $count=count($terms);
        foreach ($form['field_company']['und']['#options'] as $key=>$value) {
            if ($key == '_none') continue;
            $delete=true;
            for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
                if ($key == $terms[$i]) $delete = FALSE;
            }
            if ($delete) $form['field_company']['und'][$key]= array('#access' => FALSE);
        }
    }else {
        //hide field firm if user has no access to any term
        $form['field_company']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

PS: with ur comment i optimized this code. 
fetchAll() gives array of objects i do not need in objects and this is not optimal.
fetchCol() gives array that exactly i need. 
but fetchAllKeyed() gives only one element. 
thank you Paul!

Comment: You could try "->fetchCol()" (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementInterface%3A%3AfetchCol/7) to get an indexed array of tids.